# ios 5 simulator not responding in xcode 4.2

Tags: ios5, ios-simulator

Recently i updated my xcode version to the latest 4.2

In this xcode version, while running my ios 5 application in "iPad 5.0 Simulator" always the Simulator getting not respond. But i can install the same app in iPad 2. But i can't see in Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of multiple threads of same app running on simulator. Please stop all threads. Quit simulator. And run.. This worked for me.. Try yourself.

Comment: Hey the problem is because "iOS 5 Simulator" cant write files while compiling source at Library\Application Support\iPhone Simulator. I just change the write permission to iPhone Simulator directory, then it works fine. thanks for your reply!

Comment: This was driving me crazy as well...could run on my iPhone but not the Simulator, finally ended up rebooting which probably killed the threads as you indicate, and everything works now.  Man this was frustrating.